# saben como convertir una consulta de sql server a python view?

Tags: python, sql-server

estoy tratando de convertir esta consulta a python view

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(ROUND(alumno_clase.calificacion_final, 2)), 2) AS Promedio
FROM dbo.alumno
INNER JOIN alumno_clase ON alumno.matricula = alumno_clase.matricula
INNER JOIN alumno_grupo ON alumno.matricula = alumno_grupo.matricula
INNER JOIN grupo ON alumno_grupo.cve_grupo = grupo.cve_grupo
INNER JOIN clase ON alumno_clase.cve_clase = clase.cve_clase 
                 AND alumno_clase.cve_docente = clase.cve_docente 
                 AND grupo.cve_periodo = clase.cve_periodo
WHERE clase.cve_periodo = (
    SELECT cve_periodo
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP (1) cve_periodo, fecha_inicio
        FROM periodo
        WHERE fecha_inicio < (
            SELECT fecha_inicio
            FROM periodo AS periodo_1
            WHERE activo = 1
        ) AND alumno_clase.calificacion_final > 0
        ORDER BY fecha_inicio DESC
    ) AS a
) AND alumno.matricula = '612110279'
```

en las respuestas les dejo como lo estoy haciendo en python ya que estoy usando estasAvg, ExpressionWrapper, DecimalField
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP  para poder sacar el promedio ya estan los models bien importados y la conexion de la base de datos tambien solo seria eso

Comment: aqui esta la viewmatricula = '612110279'
    calificaciones = AlumnoClase.objects.filter(
        matricula__matricula=matricula,
        cve_clase__cve_periodo=Periodo.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lt=Periodo.objects.filter(activo=True).values('fecha_inicio')
   ).order_by('-fecha_inicio').values('cve_periodo')[:1] ).values('calificacion_final')
    total = 2
    count = 0
    for calificacion in calificaciones:
        total += calificacion['calificacion_final']
        count += 1
    if count > 0: promedio = round(total / count, 2)  # Cálculo del promedio
    else: promedio = 0.00

Comment: Qué has intentado? Tienes un error? Si no sabes cómo hacerlo, qué has investigado?

Comment: Ramon, bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour], por favor no dejes código en comentarios, [edit] tu pregunta y completa el código.  Por eso es importante el [tour] que te explicará cómo funcionamos por aquí. Un saludo.